# In iptables and conntrack is ESTABLISHED, RELATED the same as RELATED, ESTABLISHED when default policy is drop?

Tags: iptables

My default policy for all chains is drop. I'm trying to understand if there is a difference between the order of `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` and `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` when conntrack is entered into a rule command.

For are these two command the same?

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference depending on the order. It is just a list of one ore more states that you want to match.

If you want separate packet/byte counters, you can create two rules, one with ESTABLISHED and one with RELATED.